# Get data from table for each element IN an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to take for each value in an array the first 10 records found in a db.

Using the `IN` operator in getting all the records at once, is a better fit for me because I can group them easily, but the problem is that for each value in the array I get 100 records, and I only need the first 10 records. How can I get those?

This what I use now, but the below code is taking 100 records from the table, for each element in the array.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]

Result.where('date(created_at) = ? AND word_id IN (?)', Date.today - 1.day, arr)

o = _ 
o.group(:value).count
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question

Comment: What's your definition of "first" 10 rows?

Comment: Also, what's the RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

are looking for something like this

`arr = [1, 2, 3]`

```
result = arr.collect { |i| result << Result.where('date(created_at) = ? AND word_id IN (?)', Date.today - 1.day, i).order(:id).limit(10) }.flatten
```

or

```
result = arr.map { |i| result << Result.where('date(created_at) = ? AND word_id IN (?)', Date.today - 1.day, i).order(:id).limit(10) }.flatten
```

get the count by

`result.count`

Comment: It will work for an array with 2, 3 elements, but what will you do and you have 1000 elements or even more in the array. Also, the grouping and counting on a column will give you the duplicates. Thank you for the effort.